# Full path of *.cpp files

Tags: c++, file, boost, path

I need to have full path of C++ files (name of file is not neccesary). It musn't to be depended on path of execution.
I can use `__FILE__`, hovewer it gives me only name of file. I was seeking in boost::filesystem, but I only found `boost::filesystem::current_path()` - unfortunately it gives me path of directory from which I run program.

I looking for path of cpp file, not path of exe. I need it for other tool to generate groups of cpp files after directory of cpp files.

Any ideas?

Edit:
Maybe it is possible to use bash script which gives actual directory of cpp file (not sh file)?

Comment: Are you looking for the path within your program, or on command line in the shell?

Comment: I have edited my question. I need to use C++ language.

Comment: I use gcc-4.7.3 on Linux 64 bit. It gives me only name of file.

Comment: If `__FILE__` doesn't do it for you, then this can't be done easily and would need special compiler support.  If you're using makefiles, you might be able to do something like add `-DFULL_FILE_PATH="<filepath>"` to your compiler's command line and then use the macro `FULL_FILE_PATH` in your source code.

Comment: According to http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/453661-short-form-__file__, `__FILE__` is feeded by the compiler path given to the compiler, So can you change your tool chain to give full path of the file to your compiler ?

Comment: Related to [full-file-path-in-assert-macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449576/c-c-full-file-path-in-assert-macro)

Comment: It doesn't works for me.

Comment: How do you compile your file ? It works on coliru: [shortpath](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/969101c88ed3c859) [fullpath](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3980d6274c7d1ae)

Comment: I check it second time and it works for me. I don't know why it doesn't works before. Hovewer it need changes in method of compilation. I have many files, makefiles, so it can be difficult. I thought about something like `std::string cpp_path = system(get_current_path.sh)`. Eventually I can write script which generate files `dirname` for each directory with name of path and in *cpp files I can read this file.

Comment: Do you have something that generate the Makefile or these files are yours ? The make rule `%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(realpath $<) -o $@` should do the trick.